# Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em python, usando selenium, e para fazer ela funcionar, preciso que o chrome já abra com uma sessão iniciada

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, session

Quero que meu chrome abra já logado, para eu não precisar passar por capthas, etc.
Aqui está meu código:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

options = Options()

options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\')

driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver'

driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)

sleep(5)

print('Hello')

driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
```

E até que funciona, ele abre o Chrome já logado, porém não funciona a parte do selenim, ele apenas abre o google e fica ali, não printa nada, não vai para o instagram, nem nada.

Aparece o seguinte erro no console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\Tts\tts.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 466, in __init__    
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__  
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__ 
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 724, in start_session
    super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\VScode\FreelaGabs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:61804
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x010ECE43+45171]
        (No symbol) [0x01079091]
        (No symbol) [0x00F6BCE0]
        (No symbol) [0x00F60D21]
        (No symbol) [0x00F93A38]
        (No symbol) [0x00F8D73C]
        (No symbol) [0x00F8D56F]
        (No symbol) [0x00FC1AA6]
        (No symbol) [0x00FC163C]
        (No symbol) [0x00FBAE46]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9675E]
        (No symbol) [0x00F978FD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013A5449+2897529]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013EDBFB+3194411]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013E79D1+3169281]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011760C0+606960]
        (No symbol) [0x01082E0C]
        (No symbol) [0x0107EF98]
        (No symbol) [0x0107F0BF]
        (No symbol) [0x010717B7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x777200C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C07B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C07AEE+238]
```

Percebi que se comento a linha "driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')", não altera em nada, ou seja, ele abre o navegador já na nomeação do driver, o que eu acho que não deveria acontecer.

Estou usando python3.11

Comment: Você está usando a versão do [Chrome correspondente ao seu ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)?

Comment: **A conversa [foi movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148523/discussion-on-question-by-joao-pedro-sedrez-estou-desenvolvendo-uma-aplicacao-em)**. Evitem longas conversas nos comentarios, revejam a [proposta dos comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Para futuras perguntas é importante sempre fornecer um [mcve] do problema, de forma a facilitar a identificação e servir como referência para futuros visitantes. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.